# Openshift new-app from image creates service with incorrect ports

Tags: openshift

I am using openshift oc new-app to create a app from a image.

However oc new-app is creating the associated openshift service incorrectly with only one tcp port, not the two ports than the application uses.

Is there any simple way to force openshift new-app to correctly create the service with the two correct ports when building from a image rather than incorrectly with only one port ?

Alternatively is there a command line way to add the extra port to the service created that can be scripted (I know about oc edit) ..
(Disclaimer.. I am new to openshift and have lots to learn)

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the ports exposed by the service are introspected based on labels in the builder image. E.g., https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-python-container/blob/master/3.9/Dockerfile.rhel8#L39. So, looking at the python builder image, it's exposing port 8080. If you're using one of the built-in S2I builder images, you won't be able to override the exposed ports. If you're providing your own builder image, then be sure to set your `LABEL` appropriately.

Comment: In this case I am using a third party supplied image, artifactory-oss, for the opensource artifactory repo .

Comment: If you don't own the image, your only 2 options are to either create your own image (you can use the original image as a base, `FROM <original image>`, in your Dockerfile)...or you create your own `Service` object exposing the ports you want.